# Hive Join on 2 tables one has partition other does not

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I have to tables lets say table one is X and table two is Z.

Table Z has a partition predicate.

Table X is a country table which has the following fields

`country_id, country_name`

Table Z contains some data and I want to map the `country_id` of that table with Table X.

I tried this

```
select c.country_id, c.country_name, s.sales_id, s.sales_ctry_id 
from x_table c 
join z_table s 
on (c.country_id=s.sales_ctry_id)
```

but because table Z is partitioned by a date field,  I can't get this join to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I added a where statement  on (c.country_id=sales.ctry_id where sales.dt='20171010') But still it fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `WHERE`, you should add the additional partition predicate to the join predicate using `AND`.

`ON (c.country_id=sales.ctry_id AND sales.dt='20171010')`